# How do I pass existing logged in web app user to Azure Web chat bot so that only authenticated and authorized user can use web chat bot?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I want to host or embed a Azure Web Chat bot in existing web application using Web chat control on client side. The user will have to login to the web application first in order to use web chat bot feature in the web app.

If I have a user who is already logged in to my web app, what mechanism can I  use to pass that user to Web chat control JavaScript?

I was checking the sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and the source code for embedding web chat looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN' }),
        userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
        username: 'Web Chat User',
        locale: 'en-US',
        botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
        userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> So does this mean I will have to generate or get the loggedin user ID
>   and name and pass it to **username** and **userID** for every new user
>   session on web app?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, userID, username, locale, botAvatarInitials, and userAvatarInitials are all optional parameters to pass into the renderWebChat method.

If userID is not specified, it will default to a random user ID. Multiple users sharing the same user ID is not recommended; their user state will be shared.

A similar issue was discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804506/how-do-i-automatically-pass-user-information-to-the-bot-framework-conversation-i).

Also please checkout this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to use authentication for your bot via the bot service using C# and JS.